# Virtual Hosts on Apache2 loading same site for all hosts

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, virtualhost, vhosts

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 with Apache2.4.7

I enabled both the sites using a2ensite and reloaded apache2. It reloads successfully, but always shows sitea even for siteb.com or www.siteb.com

sitea.conf has following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitea.com
    ServerAlias www.sitea.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerRoot /home/sitea/
    DocumentRoot /home/sitea/www

    <Directory /home/sitea/www>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

siteb.conf has following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName siteb.com
    ServerAlias www.siteb.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerRoot /home/siteb/
    DocumentRoot /home/siteb/www

    <Directory /home/siteb/www>
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Both of them have `ServerName sitea.com`.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Corrected it.